# Is the following operation atomic or not?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO my_table (pseudo_id)
    SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
    FROM information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
```

... and as parallelistic as built-in MySQL sequencing capability?

Please provide reference link(s).

Comment: Mix up of terms here? Atomic operations - are a series of operations where all of them succeed or fail, not partially succeed or fail. I think you're talking about blocking here. I would assume, it's possible for the number to be incremented after you get it's value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is atomic, because every "single-command" query (even if it contains subqueries) is atomic.

(Well, this is valid for InnoDB engine and now I'm not sure if it's also valid for MyISAM....)

Comment: @joe, so you mean this operation is not atomic on MyISAM?

Comment: I'm not sure either way. I just don't use MyISAM any more. Hence the :P

Comment: MyISAM coverage might be useful, since atomicity of such compound queries might be provided by InnoDB itself by the mean of implicit transaction/rows locking.

Comment: @joeframbach, same for me :-) Transactions are important. Use MyISAM if you want fast & inconsistent db, or get screwed by locking :-)